# Database of altcoins?

Tags: address, altcoin, database

Is there a database of all the major altcoins and their address types?

[Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_alternative_cryptocurrencies) doesn't have very many, nor does it describe their address formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md

For those using the BIP44 "purpose" field anyway.

That "major" qualifier will be slippery

From my notes so far

...

Alternative coins

Wallet clients do not keep track of which coin types you own

...

shitcoins

stablecoins

intended for payments, value tokens

...

ETH Ethereum

BNB Binance Coin

XMR Monero

LTC Litecoin

ADA Cardano

DOT Polkadot

...

Others

• SOL Solana

• AVAX Avalanche

• USDC USD Coin LINK Chainlink

• ALGO Algorand

• MATIC Polygon

• VET VeChain

• TRX Tron

• ZEC ZCash

• XTZ Tezos

• NEO

• DASH

• STX Stacks

• NEM

• DCR Decred

• STORJ

• ZRX Ox

• DGB DigiByte

Comment: Please don't mess with my answer! Post your own